# AWS EKS Kubernetes pods taking a lot of time to get READY

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, microservices, kubectl, amazon-eks

Github repo: https://github.com/oussamabouchikhi/udagram-microservices

After I configured the kubectl with the AWS EKS cluster, I deployed the services using these commands

```
kubectl apply -f env-configmap.yaml
kubectl apply -f env-secret.yaml
kubectl apply -f aws-secret.yaml
# this is repeated for all services 
kubectl apply -f svcname-deploymant.yaml
kubectl apply -f svcname-service.yaml
```

[image]

But the pods took hours and still in PENDING state, and when I run the command `kubectl describe pod <POD_NAME>` I get the follwing info

reverseproxy-667b78569b-2c6hv pod: https://pastebin.com/3xF04SEx 
udagram-api-feed-856bbc5c45-jcgtk pod: https://pastebin.com/5UqB79tU 
udagram-api-users-6fbd5cbf4f-qbmdd pod: https://pastebin.com/Hiqe1LAM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your `kubectl describe pod <podname>`

> Warning  FailedScheduling  2m19s (x136 over 158m)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 Too many pods.

When you see this, it means that your nodes in AWS EKS is full.

**To solve this, you need to add more (or bigger) nodes.**

You can also investigate your nodes, e.g. list your nodes with:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

and investigate a specific node (check how many pods it has *capacity* for - and how many pods that runs on the node) with:

```
kubectl describe node <node-name>
```

Comment: When you say bigger you mean more GB or bigger instance type? I am using t2.micro as an instance type and 5GB of memory size

Comment: You need an instance type with more ENIs, see AWS documentation about Elastic Network Interfaces

Comment: I will check that, thank you!